# Le pronom neutre « le » est-il facultatif ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

> Lors donc que tu fais l’aumône, ne sonne pas de la trompette devant toi, comme font les hypocrites dans les synagogues et dans les rues, afin d’être glorifiés par les hommes. (Segond 1910, Mathieu 6.2)
>
> Donc, lorsque tu fais un don à quelqu’un, ne sonne pas de la trompette
>   devant toi, comme **le** font les hypocrites dans les synagogues et dans
>   les rues afin de recevoir la gloire qui vient des hommes. (Segond 21, L'original avec les mots d'aujourd'hui, Ibid.)

La présence du pronom neutre *le* est-elle nécessaire dans ce cas ? Pourquoi ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oui, les deux formes sont possibles et équivalentes mais la tendance est à l'utilisation du pronom *le*. Son absence est aujourd'hui plus littéraire et très rare en français parlé.

[image]

[image]